# Check if Whole Number for large Value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

The isWholeNumber Method works fine for number less than 16 digits but it does not work with larger values. How do i find if a large digit is whole number or not ?

```
var isWholeNumber = num => num % 1 == 0;

isWholeNumber(900719925443099.122) // false

isWholeNumber(9007199254430991.122) // true
```

Comment: Hint: try printing the second value to the console.

Comment: i just did. the result it same. Let me know if i am missing anything ?

Comment: I think you need a big number library for this check. The problem is the limitation of the numeric type in Javascript.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `isWholeNumber` method ? Do you want to check whether it is numeric value or non-numeric ? And expected output for both should be true ?

Comment: @SpiderCode i would like to check if the number passed is wholeNumber or not.  Both should be false as both are not complete whole numbers.

Comment: @gil.fernandes is there a way without library. ?

Comment: @RohailNajam I do not think there is, because Javascript has this limitation on its number type. So what you cannot do with native tools, you have to do with some libraries.

Comment: @gil.fernandes Alright thanks :)

Comment: You could convert it to a string and look if there is a dot in it like this: `isWholeNumber = num => num.contains(".")` Not a very elegant solution but i think it would work

Comment: @ochs.tobi : This will also not work. Because of limitation it will truncate last digits.